# Vue.js set component data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I have a Map.vue component, and I would like to change its data. However I don't know how to do this in Vue.js :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="google-map" :id="mapName">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'google-map',
  props: ['name'],
  methods:{ 
    updateCurrentPosition(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.$data.currentLocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        console.log("After setting, This.currentLocation = ");
        console.log(this.$data.currentLocation);

        this.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(this.$data.currentLocation.lat, this.$data.currentLocation.lng));
        this.map.setZoom(18);
      });      
    },  

    initializeMap(){
      this.updateCurrentPosition(); 

      console.log("Before Marker, This.currentLocation = ");
      console.log(this.$data.currentLocation);

      this.addMarker(this.$data.currentLocation);
    },

    addMarker(LatLngObj){
      console.log("In addMarker This.currentLocation = ");
      console.log(this.$data.currentLocation);  

      var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(LatLngObj.lat, LatLngObj.lng),
        map:this.map,
        icon:'http://www.magic-emoji.com/emoji/images/619_emoji_iphone_ok_hand_sign.png'
      });
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      mapName: this.name + "-map",
      markerCoordinates: [{
        latitude: 51.501527,
        longitude: -0.1921837
      }, {
        latitude: 51.505874,
        longitude: -0.1838486
      }, {
        latitude: 51.4998973,
        longitude: -0.202432
      }],
      map: null,
      bounds: null,
      markers: [], 
      currentLocation:{}
    }
  },
```

this.$data.currentLocation has a correct value in updateCurentPosition(), but once outside this function, it is just a blank object. How can I set its value so it accessible from other functions ?

Comment: Please define what you mean by outside?

Comment: When I print this.$data.currentLocation in updateCurentPosition(), the object has a Lat and Lng. But when I print it in another function(outside) after having it set, the print shows a blank object.

Comment: Don't use `$data` when referring to it. It's just `this.currentLocation`.

Comment: I still have a problem, this.currentLocation has the right lat & lng in updateCurentPosition(), but when I print it in another function it is still blank.

Comment: Where is the other function and what handle does it use in place of `this` to get the same component instance? Is there any way you can distill this down to a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.currentLocation` instead of `this.$data.currentLocation`.

You've been confused by `data () { return { currentLocation: null } }` object which tell vuejs to add `currentLocation` in his reactivity system.

But all properties defined in this data object are accessible directly by `this`.